# ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes RequiredIf validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, expressiveannotations

I have the following validation not working and cannot resolve why that is the case?

```
    [Display(Name = "Bus")]
    [RequiredIf("SelectedWidgetText == 'Referral'", ErrorMessage = "Please select a Vehicle.")]
    public int DepotId{ get; set; }

    public string SelectedWidgetText { get; set; }
```

I have also tried the following:

```
[Display(Name = "Bus")]
[AssertThat("SelectedWidgetText == 'Referral'", ErrorMessage = "Please select a Vehicle.")]
public int DepotId{ get; set; }
```

on the server side, when the modelstate.isvalid method is hit, it returns false and the error message thrown is `The DepotId field is required.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just by changing the `DepotId` to `Nullable` like the following, the validation started working as expected:

`public int? DepotId{get;set;}`

After reading the documentation, looks like the value types have to be nullable before the data annotation will work on them.